# Undefined offset: 0 Error Messages

Tags: php, magento

I am getting thousands of these errors in my Magento system.log:

```
2013-08-31T09:49:12+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 0  in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Infortis/Ultimo/Block/Navigation.php on line 255
2013-08-31T09:49:12+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 0  in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Infortis/Ultimo/Block/Navigation.php on line 286
2013-08-31T09:49:12+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 0  in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Infortis/Ultimo/Block/Navigation.php on line 255
2013-08-31T09:49:12+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 0  in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Infortis/Ultimo/Block/Navigation.php on line 286
```

You can see the code these refer to in the attached image.

Any ideas?

[image: Code]

Comment: Can you show us the output of 

`echo '<pre>',print_r($res_2),'</pre>';`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use isset() function on those lines (255,286), like this:

```
elseif(isset($res_2[0]) && $res_2[0] != NULL)
```

That way it will first find out whether the index exists and only if it does it will access it and compare it´s value.

Or to keep things simple and since you use non-equal operator, you could use just [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function, which will work the same as previous solution, like this:

```
elseif(!empty($res_2[0]))
```